# How to create Dashboard in Yii2? I want to list of employee with some detail

Tags: php, yii2

On Dashboard I want to list employees with detail, I am trying to create table in  `<div class="col-lg-4" style="border:solid 1px;">` but width height can not be set here.

Comment: please share us your code.

Comment: Without knowing your code, how can we help.? **You only say**

Comment: Don't ask this type question's first try yourself , If you get stuck any where search in google , I am sure you find an answer if don't find the answer that put question on stack. Other wise you will get Downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an example for `ActiveDataProdvider`:

the controller:

```
public function actionCustomers(){

    $query = new \yii\db\Query;
    $query->select('*')
            ->from('customers')
            ->limit(10);
    $query->createCommand();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => false,
    ]);

    return $this->render('customers', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    ]);
}
```

the view:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\CustomersSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Customers';
?>

<div class="customers-index">
    <div class="grids">
        <div id="customers-grids">
        <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => [
                [
                    'attribute' => 'image',
                    'format' => 'html',
                    'label' => 'Profile Image',
                    'value' => function ($data) {
                        return Html::img('@web/images/customers/' . $data['image'],
                            ['width' => '96px']);
                    },
                ],
                'id',
                 [
                    'attribute' => 'fullName',
                    'format' => 'raw',
                    'label' => 'Customer Full Name',
                    'value' => function ($data) {
                        return $data['firstname']." ".$data['lastname'];
                    },
                ],
                'phone',
                'email:email',
                [
                    'attribute' => 'customerBookings',
                    'format' => 'raw',
                    'label' => 'No. of Bookings',
                    'value' => function($data){
                      return "12 Bookings<br/>8 Orders";  
                    },
                ],

                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'header'=>'Action'],
            ],
        ]); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p class="add">
        <?= Html::a('', ['create'], ['class' => '']) ?>
    </p>

</div>
```

**NOTE:** I used some customized columns in the `GridView` widget.

Comment: Thanks, Your code really understandable for me...

Comment: Can you tell me how to write 2 different dataProvider in one action and render to same page

Comment: @priyankaahire in the controller, just create another data provider same as the above, with a different variable name surly, then send it as a parameter in the render function, so if you named the new data provider as $dataProvider2, the render should be like this:

`return $this->render('customers', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'dataprovider2'=>$dataProvider2
    ]);`

Comment: I have write 2 $dataProvider but how to set them in index.php

Comment: @priyankaahire show me your code please

Comment: @priyankaahire I've edited your question, please remove these two comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98111/discussion-between-priyanka-ahire-and-mohammad).